# Solving the integral $\int_{c - i \infty}^{c + i \infty}{x^n e^{xt} dx}$ given by an inverse laplace transform.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

After an inverse laplace transform I obtain that

$$f(t) = \int_{c - i \infty}^{c + i \infty}{x^n e^{xt} dx}$$

Where $c$ is a constant in the fundamental strip and $n \in N$.

I am trying to calculate this integral for various values of $c$ but going nowhere.

How could this be done?

Comment: @Chappers yes, sorry, I edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^ne^{xt}\,dx$ fails to exist.

However, we note that as a distribution the Laplace Transform of the Dirac Delta is

$$F(s)=\mathscr{L}\{\delta\}=1$$

Therefore the inverse Laplace Transform of $1$ is

$$f(t)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{1\}=\delta(t)$$

Furthermore, we have

$$\frac{d^nf(t)}{dt^n}=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left(\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F\}\right)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{s^nF(s)\}$$

Setting $F(s)=1$, we find that the inverse Laplace Transform of $s^n$ is given by

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{s^nF(s)\}=\delta^{(n)}(t)$$

while $\delta^{(n)}(t)$ is the $n$'th derivative of the Dirac Delta.

> While the inverse Laplace Transform of $s^n$ as given by the Bromwich integral
>
> $$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}s^ne^{st}\,ds$$
>
> fails to exist, we can broaden the interpretation of the Laplace Transform and its inverse to include generalized functions.

Comment: Thank you greatly, could you give me a reference to study for this broadening of the Laplace transform?

Comment: Also, is there an easy way to see the integral always diverges?

Comment: very nice use of distributional Laplace transforms (+1)

Comment: @tired Thank you as always!

Comment: @Monolite I don't have a specific reference.  But Gelfand and Shiov's book, "[Generalized Functions: Properties and Operations](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=gelfand+and+shilov)" is a good place to start.

Comment: @Monolite We can write the integral as $ie^{ct}\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty (c+iy)^ne^{iyt}\,dy$.  Heuristically, as $y\to \infty$, the amplitude of the oscillations are growing as $y^n$ and therefore the absolute value of the improper integral grows without bound.

Comment: Thank you Mark one last thing: I can't quite understand how broadening the Laplace Transform could help from your example. In the example you are saying that although the Laplace Transform of the delta function should not exist we can obtain it anyway treating it as a generalized function? am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Oh no I think I understand now, you have given me exactly the solution I was looking for. Correct? it seems weird to me that the result is a functional (distribution) and not a function, maybe I have to think some more upon it.

Comment: @MarkViola Nice answer(+1)! Would you specify the definition of the Laplace transform for distributions? I know how the Fourier transform is defined for the tempered distributions but didn't found the definition for the Laplace transform of distributions.

Comment: @S.H.W Thank you.  Much appreciated.  [HERE](https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-d/da6d78333f34b01f4a33dd82567e5c34) is an article that you might find useful.  And [HERE](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-65690-3_12) is a book that you might like to examine.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you so much for your suggestions.

Comment: @S.H.W You're welcome.  My pleasure.